# Universal space for all topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

This problem is from General Topology, revised and complete edition, Engelking. 2.3.I.
Let $E$ be the topological space, $E=\{0,1,2\}$ with the topology consisting of the empty set, the set $\{0\}$, and the whole space. Show that the space $E^m$ is universal for all topological spaces of weight $m \ge \aleph_0$ (Aleph null) and cardinality less than or equal to $2^m$. Note that every topological space is homeomorphic to a subspace of a power of $E$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by weight?

Comment: Given a topological space X, the weight of X, denoted by w(X)=min{|B|:B is a base of X}

Comment: Note that $E^m$ has weight $m$ and size $2^m$ so any subspace must obey the same restrictions. Hence $w(X) \le m$ and $|X| \le 2^m$.

Comment: Yes, this was my next question. |E|=3, so |$E^m$|=$|E|^m$=$3^m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use the embedding theorem 2.3.20.

We have a base $\mathcal{B}$ of size at most $\mathbf{m}$, and for each $B$ in that base define $f_B: X \to E$ by $f_B(x)=0$ for $x \in B$ and $f_B(x)=1$ for $x \notin B$. This is continuous as $f_B[\{0\}]= B$ is open, and $\{0\}$ is the only non-trivial open set of $E$. Note that $\{f_B: B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ separates points and closed sets, because $\mathcal{B}$ is a base.

We would be done if $X$ were a $T_0$ space, because then these functions would *also* separate points (2.3.26 states this fact).

To get an embedding in the general we need to add functions $f$ from $X$ to $E$ that are continuous and separate points for the all other points as well. That's why we have two extra points besides $0$ (otherwise Sierpiński space would have sufficed, again 2.3.26): any function $f$ on $X$ that only takes values $1,2 \in E$ is always continuous, as $f^{-1}[\{0\}]=\emptyset$ etc.

Finally, simply by set theory and as $|X| \le 2^{\mathbf{m}}$, we can find an injection $i: X \to \{1,2\}^{\textbf{m}}$ (this does use AC, but that's assumed throughout in Engelking's text). Then add all functions $\pi_\alpha \circ i: X \to E, \alpha \in \mathbf{m}$, which are continuous by the remark above, to the $\{f_B: B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ to get a family  of size $\mathbf{m} + \mathbf{m} = \mathbf{m}$ many continuous functions that separates points and closed sets, and also separates points.

Then 2.3.20 finishes the job.

Comment: The base can have cardinality at least m.

Comment: I am not sure that I quite understand you. You add to those m functions some other functions, which are at most m and separate the points. And then you argue that m+m=m and construct the embedding.

Comment: How do we know that we have this many topologically distinct pts?

Comment: @КалинВърбанов Weight $\mathbf{m}$ means there is at least one base of that size, so pick one. Yes the functions from the base are the first approximation, but we need to add a set of at most $\mathbf{m}$ functions to separate the points. You have to think about why we only need that many and not $|X|$ many (no spoilers yet).

Comment: And so for each pair of different pts we define a function that takes values 1 and 2. How many functions are that?

Comment: And at the end we still have m functions, is that right?

Comment: Don't we neet these functions for the topologically indistinguishable points?

Comment: @КалинВърбанов Yes, as I said. If points are distinguishable we can already separate them.

Comment: OK, I don't know, the number of maps from X to {1,2} is $2^m$, there is an injection from X to P(B)... What to use, pls give me a hint!

Comment: How to show that there are at most m indistinguishable points?

Comment: Yes, it has cardinality m.

Comment: m, I think, bcs the base is a cover

Comment: But wait, they are not necessarily disjoint.

Comment: I don't understand the question, we need to have a disjoint cover in order to speak about classes.

Comment: And what are the classes?

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of this result?

Comment: @КалинВърбанов I gave the full argument now. It was trivial.

Comment: Aaa, now I got it!

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111240/discussion-between---and-henno-brandsma).